# How to show columns from different table in TABLE FORM?

Tags: html

I want to show this row as a table form:

```
<?php
   while($row = $ogdata->fetch_array()){
?>
<?php  
   echo "<input type='radio' disabled>".$row['text']; 
   $ans = $row['is_answer'];
   if($ans == 1)
      echo "<span style=font-family;color:green;>&nbsp;<div class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'>CorrectAnswer</div></span>";
?>                                           
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to join the tables in your mysql query.